# Flutter - blur the screen except the selected widget

Tags: flutter, dart, overlay, blur, popupmenu

We have a screen with listItems. Each item can be longPressed to open a popupMenu. Now requirement is to blur the screen except the selected listItem on long press. (check screenshot)

[image: list with popupMenu]

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Take a look at this answer on [make frosted glass effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43550853/how-do-i-do-the-frosted-glass-effect-in-flutter),maybe it help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this one.
https://pub.dev/packages/focused_menu

Using this library you can show the popup menu by making the background blurry without the tapped item.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!